# Cron job for everyday at 5pm

Tags: javascript, cron, schedule, cron-task

I want to run a cron job at 17:00 everyday. Which one is the correct format?

`0 17 * * *`  or  `0 */17 * * *`

or are they both same? Please do tell the difference.

Answer (score 4):

The first is correct - it runs at 17:00 each day. The second runs *every* 17 hours. So 17:00 the first day, 10am the next and so on.
You can test your cron configurations at [https://crontab.guru/](https://crontab.guru/#). Other similar sites are available.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are a list of examples for CRON tasks ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp)):

[image]

[image]